# Evaluate $ \int_0^{\infty} dx \, \, \frac{\sin(a \arctan(\frac{x}{k}))}{x^b (k^2 + x^2)^{a/2}}$

Tags: calculus, integration, complex-analysis

I came across this integral
$$ \int_0^{\infty} dx \, \, \frac{\sin(a \arctan(\frac{x}{k}))}{x^b (k^2 + x^2)^{a/2}}, $$
with $a+b > 1>b$. It is stated that this integral is equal to 
$$ \frac{\pi \Gamma(a+b-1)}{2\,k^{a+b-1}\,\sin(\frac{b\pi}{2}) \, \Gamma(a) \Gamma(b)} .$$
I am interested in proving this, but where to start? Using residues?

Comment: Assuming $a$ and $k$ are positive, $\frac{\sin \left(a \arctan \frac{x}{k}\right)}{(k^2+x^2)^{a/2}} = - 
\text{Im} \, \frac{1}{(k+ix)^{a}}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set $x=kz$ and $dx= k\,dz$ you are left with
$$ \frac{1}{k^{a+b-1}}\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin(a\arctan z)}{z^b (z^2+1)^{a/2}}\,dz=-\frac{1}{k^{a+b-1}}\cdot\text{Im}\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{z^b(1+iz)^a}\,dz $$
and the last integral is simple to compute through a substitution and [Euler's Beta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function),
 leading to:
$$ \frac{1}{k^{a+b-1}}\cdot\text{Im}\left(ie^{-\pi i b/2}\,B(1-b,a+b-1)\right) $$
The claim then follows from the $\Gamma$ reflection formula $\Gamma(b)\,\Gamma(1-b) = \frac{\pi}{\sin(\pi b)}$.